# How do you set up automatic scrolling for a chat app

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, chat

I am making a chat web app for and I am mostly done besides implementing a login system but there is one problem that I can't seem to find the answer for. It isn't very complicated.
I need to know how to make it so:

1. The chat will scroll to the bottom when the site loads
2. The chat will automatically scroll to new messages but only if the user is on the bottom of the page.

This probably isn't too hard to do but I don't even know how to scroll with javascript so thanks.
The current site is at this url: [Chat url](http://topchat.pythonanywhere.com/chat)

Comment: `window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);`

Comment: @PedroLobito Thank you for this but what about #2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before you insert the new message element, [check if the window is scrolled to the bottom](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollHeight#Problems_and_solutions), then add the element, and then [scroll to the bottom again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58885343/how-do-you-set-up-automatic-scrolling-for-a-chat-app/58885525#comment104038059_58885462) if it was.

Comment: What piece of code would I use to check if it scrolled specifically? I can't seem to get it to work, I am always getting true no matter what

Comment: ```(window.innerHeight + window.pageYOffset) >= document.body.offsetHeight - 2```

where ```2``` is the tolerance for how close to the bottom (some browsers are slightly buggy so the minimum should be 2 px)

Answer (score 1):

After receiving a new message or on page reload you can use:

```
window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);
```

---

On Page load:

```
window.onload = function() {
  window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);
};
```

---

To scroll after a receiving a new msg, you can modify the function `update_message` to :

```
function update_message(id,author,body,selfSent){
    var message = document.getElementById(id);
    if(selfSent){
        message.classList.replace("messagebox-o","messagebox-s");
        author = "You";
    }else{
        message.classList.replace("messagebox-s","messagebox-o");
    }
    message.querySelector(".author-text").innerText = author;
    message.querySelector(".body-text").innerHTML = body;
    window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight); // ADD THIS
}
```

---

Comment: I only want it to scroll down if the user is already at the bottom when the message is recieved

Comment: @Hippolippo have you ever tried scrolling to a location you are already scrolled to?

Comment: @Hippolippo If you post the relevant chat code, I may be able to tell you where to place `window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);`

Comment: @PedroLobito I know where to put it but how do I check if a user is already at the bottom of the page before I send the message request

Comment: @PedroLobito I also have a link to it